# first-chance exception access violation writing location inside QT clicked event

Tags: c++, qt, exception

I have 2 version of the same application, in the version using a Graphical UI and QT I have a runtime error:

```
first-chance exception  access violation writing location
```

referring to

```
this->secondi_totali = someint;
```

launched inside a Model Method. My Model class is:

```
class Model {

public:

friend class Controller; //dico che controller può accedere alle cose private
//friend class cronometro_qt;


/*costruttore*/
Model();


void set(int,int,int);
int get_secondi();
int get_minuti();
int get_ore();
void tick();


private:
int secondi_totali;
int secondi_trascorsi;

int secondi;
int minuti;
int ore;

};
```

the method causing the exception is this:

```
void crono::Model::set(int ore, int minuti, int secondi) {
this->secondi_totali =  ore * 3600 + 60 * minuti + secondi;
this->secondi_trascorsi = 0;
 }
```

and in the stack is called from this method:

```
void crono::Controller::set(int ore, int minuti, int secondi) {

this->modello->set(ore, minuti, secondi);

}
```

this->modello is obviously a pointer to the Model object inside the Controller item.

Well as I have previously said, I have done 2 versions of my program.

In the first,  the set() method of controller is called by a simple method of the view that is an empty class.

In the second version the set() method of controller is called by a

```
void crono::cronometro_qt::on_pushButton_clicked() { /* ... */ }
```

method.

Obviously in both version the empty view or the cronometro_qt ( subclass of QMainWindow )  have a pointer to the controller, in order to call the set() method like this:

```
this->controller->set(ore,minuti, secondi);
```

So why is the QT version throwing that exception?

Comment: It looks like your modello pointer is invalid. The second part of the message suggests this is a mere segmentation fault, not an exception (which can't happen when assigning an int anyway).

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld The modello pointer is defined in the same way in both the version. QT-less version: http://nopaste.info/d0907b6843.html and here is the QT version: http://nopaste.info/48bb11482d.html

Comment: That doesn't show how the pointer is initialized at runtime. Passing a Model& in set() but storing a pointer looks fishy.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I pasted here both the inizializations: http://nopaste.info/6b58709c85.html, but they are the same. The only difference is that since the QT-LESS-version is a demo, it auto-launches the on_pushButton_clicked() instead of waiting for the user to click on pushButton as it happens in the QT-Version

Comment: You enter the application's event loop (a.exec()) before initializing the variables. exec() doesn't return before the application exits. Move the initializations above a.exec()

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Ok,  it's working now, even though I have some other issues because of the lacking of separate threads. If you post your last comment as an answer, I am going to accept it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24022/discussion-between-mark-and-frank-osterfeld)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You enter the application's event loop (a.exec()) before initializing the variables. exec() doesn't return before the application exits. Move the initializations above a.exec().